# Android ListView And EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

Hi I know that this question have appeared here but the answers didn't help me. Ok so I have an activity with listview bounded to ArrayListAdapter for my class ZamowieniePoz.

```
 public class ZamowieniePoz {

private int _idZamowienie;
private String _plu;
private String _nazwa;
private String _ilosc;
private String _jm;
private String _uwagi;
private String _dataSync;
private int _isSync; }
```

This is my listView definitione:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:scrollbars="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"           
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_below="@id/listView" >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnWyslij"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="WYŚLIJ ZAMÓWIENIE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPowrotZamowienieAdd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="POWRÓT" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is listView row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPlu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtIlosc" 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtPlu"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25sp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is ArrayListAdapter:

```
    public class ZamowieniePozArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ZamowieniePoz> {
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<ZamowieniePoz> data=null;

        public ZamowieniePozArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ZamowieniePoz> data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId=layoutResourceId;
            this.context=context;
            this.data = data;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ZamowienieHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null) {              
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                row=inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                holder = new ZamowienieHolder();
                holder.txtPlu = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtPlu);
                holder.txtIlosc=(EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.txtIlosc);

                holder.txtIlosc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                            int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                            int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                  
                            data.get(position).setIlosc(s.toString());  
                    }
                });

                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{
                holder = (ZamowienieHolder)row.getTag();
            }

            ZamowieniePoz zamowieniePoz = data.get(position);
            holder.txtPlu.setText(zamowieniePoz.getPlu());
            holder.txtIlosc.setText(zamowieniePoz.getIlosc());

            return row;

        }


        static class ZamowienieHolder {
            TextView txtPlu;
            EditText txtIlosc;
        }

}
```

This is how I bound the adapter to listView:

```
final DbHandler db = new DbHandler(ZamowienieAddActivity.this);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); 

        arrayZamowieniePoz = db.getAllZamowienie();     

        arrayAdapterZamowieniePoz = new ZamowieniePozArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.zamowienie_add_list_items, arrayZamowieniePoz);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapterZamowieniePoz);
```

So this is it. The problem is that first row of listView duplicates last row. I think that there's something wrong with this line of code data.get(position).setIlosc(s.toString()); in getView in afterTextChange.

Please help me I don't know what is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TextWatcher` is instantiated at the same time as the row `View`

If you get a recycled View (`row != null`), in the following code

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                  
    data.get(position).setIlosc(s.toString());  
}
```

`position` will still refer to the position of the **original** view.

You need to reset the `TextWatcher` for each iteration, making sure to call [`removeTextChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#removeTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) before calling `addTextChangeListener()` again.

---

A simple implementation could be done like that, although instanciating a TextWatch each time might not be optimal :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ZamowienieHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ZamowienieHolder();
        holder.txtPlu = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtPlu);
        holder.txtIlosc = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.txtIlosc);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ZamowienieHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    // Remove previous TextWatcher if any
    if (holder.textWatcher != null) {
        holder.txtIlosc.removeTextChangedListener(holder.textWatcher);
    }

    // Create the TextWatcher corresponding to this row
    holder.textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            data.get(position).setIlosc(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    });

    holder.txtIlosc.addTextChangedListener(holder.textWatcher);

    ZamowieniePoz zamowieniePoz = data.get(position);
    holder.txtPlu.setText(zamowieniePoz.getPlu());
    holder.txtIlosc.setText(zamowieniePoz.getIlosc());

    return row;
}
```

Comment: I added a TextWatcher and make removeTextChangeListener before addTextChangeListener and i doensn't change anything. Can you post an example how to do it your way. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. THX

Comment: @user2440158 Edited my post with an example

Answer (score 0):

Bellow code using your arrayAdaper.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="Rename To: "
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ZoneRenameEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/relay_txtbox"
        android:ems="2"
        android:maxLength="50"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ZoneDoneImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:background="@drawable/bk_done_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```